# malloc.c:3074 error?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

When I write a C program, I encountered a problem that is as follows:

> malloc.c:3074: sYSMALLOc: Assertion
>   (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *)
>   &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) -
>   __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0)
>   || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >=
>   (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof
>   (struct malloc_chunk,
>   fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t)))
>   - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) &&
>   ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) ==
>   0) failed.

Please help me to fix it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a heap misuse. You shoul provide a snippet that exposes that.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a small example? With about ten lines of code.

Comment: I just using the malloc() method to get some memory. If I comment this line, this problom will not occur.

Comment: The line just like that 
char *seq=malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
Of course, there are some more line like that. But I don't know where it is.

Comment: try to use many assertions. Don't combine all those logical tests into one statement, *if* you want to locate the problem easily.

Comment: How big is the block you are attempting to allocate? (i.e. what is the parameter to malloc?)

Comment: FS#15422 - [wmix] latest update breaks malloc.c ?  http://bugs.archlinux.org/task/15422?dev=allan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the administration kept for memory allocation has been corrupted. My guess would be that you have something like a buffer overflow somewhere before this error occurs.

As the error is a result of an earlier problem (assuming I'm right), this can be a somewhat difficult problem to fix. Perhaps a tool like valgrind can help you to detect incorrect writes to memory. If you have a small program that demonstrates the problem, I would suggest adding that code to your question.

Comment: My program is a little large, I can't display all the codes here.