# malloc error C++

Tags: c++, malloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [malloc.c:3074 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097995/malloc-c3074-error)

I am getting this strange error on execution of my C++ code:

```
malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

The program runs fine upto a point where it catches the above Segmentation fault(SIGSEGV) from an already executed line. I found out this using gdb.

Comment: accept other questions and show some code what yo calling this function

Comment: Can you show us the line of code itself that's failing?

Comment: Are you sure you're programming in C++ (and not in C)? `malloc()` shouldn't be used in C++. You might want to re-tag this question.

Comment: @sbi: This is from the GNU library, where the default `operator new()` calls `malloc()`.

Comment: @Mike: I'm not sure how you can tell that from the question, but, yes, that would explain the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something has corrupted the heap by writing to an invalid memory location. The most likely causes are writing outside the bounds of an allocated object, or writing to an object after it has been deleted.

These errors can be difficult to track down with a debugger. The best tool is a memory checker, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Comment: it was a silly mistake and valgrind pointed out where exactly the mistake was  .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement that the breaking line is called previously in program's execution and runs without fail to a point: This error is prabably caused by "damaged" memory structures.

This kind of strange and inconsistent behavior can be expected if you were to allocate memory and overrun writing to the buffer or if you were to allocate memory and then use the returned address without checking it to ensure that it is a non-zero address (memory allocation failure).